# gtk4-rs: Get Monitors as gdk::Monitor not as a glib::Object

Tags: rust, gtk, gobject, gdk, gtk4

I'm using the gtk4-layer-shell rust bindings and want to position my window on a specific monitor.

I have the following code:

```
let monitors: gio::ListModel = gdk::Display::default().unwrap().monitors();

let monitor: glib::Object = monitors.item(0).unwrap();
```

Thus I get the monitor as a `glib::Object`. But gtk4-layer-shell expects a `gdk::Monitor` to passed to `window.set_monitor`. I don't know how to work further with the `glib::Object`.

Libraries used: gtk4-rs, gdk4, gtk4-layer-shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`monitor.downcast::<gdk::Monitor>()`](https://gtk-rs.org/gtk-rs-core/stable/0.18/docs/glib/object/trait.Cast.html#method.downcast) to convert a `glib::Object` instance into a `gdk::Monitor`.

Comment: Thank you very much! Didn't knew about that. Where did you find it as for me it was not that obvious from the docs? @Jmb